# Geospatial Analytics - MQTT connection issue on BlueMix

Tags: node.js, analytics, geospatial, ibm-cloud, mqtt

I completed the following tutorial:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-monitordevices-app/index.html

Next, I launch the app on BlueMix and click on the geo-starter Visualizer link. It launches the screen but I cannot see any of the connected devices on my screen. See screenshot of debug mode in browser. It seems like I am unable to connect to the MQTT server from my environment. This looks like a possible issue with the firewall on my network.

Couple questions:

1. How do I debug this further to determine if this is a firewall issue or something else?
2. The MQTT server seems to communicate via port 1883 as per instructions to the MQTT server url, see below:
   mqtt1.m2m4connectedlife.com:1883
   If my network is potentially blocking this port, is there an alternative port I can use such as port 80 to communicate with the MQTT server?

Would greatly appreciate any feedback on this!

Thanks!
[mqtt-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEpEo.png)

Comment: One way to check for a firewall or DNS problem is to use a web based MQTT client from the same browser to try to connect to the same URL.  You could try a test with the one at hivemq.com to connect to the same server and subscribe to the geo-starter topic:
 
http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/

Answer (score 0):

The corporate firewall was in fact the issue here.  They won't allow traffic out on alternative ports without authorization which takes time.  This port is reserved for MQTT traffic so hopefully it can be opened up once the traffic is better understood.